# Intuitive meaning of variational extremum

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Suppose we have a functional $F$ for which the first variation vanishes for some function $f(\vec{x})$. Suppose further that the quadratic form (matrix) associated to the second variation, evaluated at $f$ has only, say, positive eigenvalues.

We can then assume, if I understand correctly, that $f$ is a (weak) local minimum of $F$ in function space.

I'm a little confused conceptually about how parameters of $f$ can affect this conclusion (or how strong it is). For instance, is it still possible $f$ has some fixed parameter (i.e. one that was not optimized over or considered in taking the variational derivatives) that could (say) make $F$ arbitrarily large at $f$? In other words what do these conclusions mean for *classes* of parameterized functions, intuitively, i.e. are they somehow constrained by being extrema?

Comment: There are two steps. First suppose that $f$ minizises your functional. Then necessarily, it must verify the equations implied by the first and second variations. Now you are right, the converse is not necessarily automatic and is done on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thanks @justt. So if a class of functions (i.e. with different fixed parameters, say) satisfies the first and second variation properties (as a whole, so to speak), it is still a local minimum of the functional (right?). I guess what's weird to me is, as the function changes (i.e. the parameter), it still remains as a minimizer. Or should I not consider this issue because the parameter was not included as a variable in the variational equations?